# PHP Debugging, $_SERVER Not all superglobals are shown in debugger

Tags: php, debugging, superglobals

I was using a debugger in VScode: called PHP Debug 1.13.0.
And XDebug installed on PC.
When I open superglobals I don't see many of them which are actually exists and printable like "$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']". Why are not all of them mentioned in debugger?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug PHP code (assuming you do not have a configured debugger, or if your debugger is not working properly) is with var_dump(). In your case, something like:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['method_name']);
```

Also, you can set up a breakpoint that will terminate program execution with die(), AND give you all the variable info that you need:

```
die(var_dump($_SERVER['method_name']));
```

Comment: _“The best way to debug PHP code is with var_dump()”_ - not really. Only if you don’t have a _real_ debugger (like XDebug) configured, and therefor you have to rely on debug _outputs_. The question here however is _explicitly_ about a problem with a real debugger.

Comment: Good point, I edited my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff, thank you for your answer, but when you debugging the big application with lots of third-party libraries it is really more convenient to have the actual debugger with help of which you can execute code line by line and see all the variable's values. I would rather have one of such which will show the whole scope of variables.